# how to input multiple strings followed by newline

Tags: c, string

this program asks about how many strings user wants to enter then it takes all strings and stores it.each string is followed by newline which signifies new string is being entered.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i;
    char str[20];

    scanf("%d",&n); //how many string

    //input each string
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s",&str[i]);
    }

    //display each string
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%s",str[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

there are two problems i'm facing 
first whenever i compile and run it in devc++ after taking input of strings program crashes
second i just want to know what i'm doing above is right ?

Comment: problem solved ! thanks to all it's always a pleasure to learn from stackoverflow . Now my second step is to sort each string in dictionary order and display it accordingly ! hope i'll be able to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is a 2D character array, which is effectively an array of strings:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int n,i;
char str[20][20]; // Can store 20 strings, each of length 20

scanf("%d",&n); //how many string

//input each string
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   scanf("%s",str[i]);
}

//display each string
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   printf("%s",str[i]);
   printf("\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

The above code runs fine. The changes I have made to your original code are:

- Declared str as a 2D array of characters, which, as mentioned, is effectively an array of strings.
- Removed the & from before str[i]. An & is not needed when scanf is used to read in a string
- Added a new line character after each string is printed to make it look more like the input code

Comment: your code worked right but i've one doubt in my code                 printf("%s",str[i])                                                made program to crash but in your code it is working properly . why ?

Comment: That was because you read in the string with an &str[i].
Remove the &str[i], and replace it with str[i], and it should work fine.

Comment: got it sorry i've added & in scanf that caused printf statement wrong..doubt solved thanx all of you .

Comment: btw i've learnt that for displaying 2d array we need 2 for loops(nested) but here it is working fine with single loop in both the cases i.e in printf as well as scanf ? how pls explain ?

Comment: That because, when you use 2 loops, you read it in character by character. Here, we're working with the entire string at a time.
So, to read in and write a SET of strings, a single loop suffices.
If you wanted to read character by character, you could use:
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        int j=0;
        char c;
        while((c=getchar())!='\n')
        {
            str[i][j++] = c;
        }
        str[i][j] = '\0';
    }

Answer (score 1):

A `char str[20]` declares an array of `20` characters not `20` strings.

This following loop in your code will write the first string starting at the start of `str`, and then write the second string starting at `str + 1`, which will overwrite the second and subsequent characters of the first string that you wrote.

```
//input each string
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    scanf("%s",&str[i]);
}
```

The reason why your program segfaults is because, in the following line `%s` requires a string (`char*`) but you are passing it a `char`.

```
printf("%s",str[i]);
```

Here is a fixed version of your code that should support as many strings as your system has memory for.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 1024
int main()
{
    int n,i;
    char ** str;

    scanf("%d",&n); //how many string

    // Allocate enough memory to store the number of strings requested
    str = malloc(n * sizeof(char*));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        str[i] = malloc((MAX_STRING_SIZE + 1) * sizeof(char));
        memset(str[i], 0, MAX_STRING_SIZE + 1);
    }

    //input each string
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s", str[i]);
    }

    // display each string
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",str[i]);
    }

    // Free the memory we allocated
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        free(str[i]);
    free(str);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your piece of code `str` is an array of 20 chars. But you need an array of 20 strings of say 100 chars.

If you write:

```
char str[20][100];
```

your program will work.

You can now enter at most 20 strings, each having a length of at most 100 characters terminating zero included.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach will be to have the memory dynamically allocated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int n,i;
   char** str;

   scanf("%d", &n);
   str = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*n);

   for(i=0; i<n; i++)
   {
      str[i] = (char*)malloc(100); // assuming the strings will not be more than 100 chars long.
      scanf("%s", &str[i]);
   }

   for(i=0; i<n; i++)
      free(str[i]);
   free(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you understand the concept of strings in C.
In C (and C++) a string is just an array of characters which ends with NULL (ASCII value - 0).
When you declared `char str[20];` you declared only one string with place for 19 characters (as NULL takes 1 character of the string). If you wanted to declare an array of strings you should have done something like this `char strs[20][100];` which will be a 2D array of characters - and in our case - 1D array of strings. It may contain 20 strings in the size of 99 characters + NULL or 100 strings at the size of 19 characters + NULL - depends the way you want it to be (usually you would treat it as 20 strings sized 99 + NULL).
The line `scanf("%s", str[i]);` is actually getting the input starting from the spot you mentioned in the string and ends it with null.

```
char str[20];
scanf("%s", str);
```

(Notice - if it's the first spot - no need for & operator) with an input "banana" would end with a string with a NULL in the spot [6] (as strings and arrays go from 0 to the size declared-1).
BUT:

```
scanf("%s", &str[4]);
```

for example - the input would be starting from the 5th spot ([4]) and ending depends on the input. If you used this scanf then you'll probably have garbage values in str[0] to str[3] as you didn't do anything in it.
Don't let the name confuse you - char str[20] - is only one string with the size of 19 characters + NULL.
The correct way would be:

```
char str[20][20]; //20 strings with the size of 19 character + NULL
int i, n;
printf("Enter the number of strings you want to enter: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
{
scanf("%s", &str[i]);
}
```

and that's it.
I hope I helped :)

Comment: thanks you cleared my doubt and also clarified the concept of strings i always had a hard time learning this. thank you !